# Rails STI and the setting of the "type" string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, sti

I think I need to use STI in Rails.

Here's my class:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Landlord < Person
end
```

and the people table has a `:type` column that's a string.

So, what I expect is to see in the table, is that every row that is a Person has the type set to "Person" and every Landlord has the type set to "Landlord".  However, that's not what I see.  Each Landlord has the type set to "Landlord", but all the Person have their type set to nil.  This very well could be the way that rails works, but I was just looking for some confirmation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is, indeed, how STI works. The base class has a type of NULL in the database (or nil in ruby).

Comment: @ioquatix because as the answer says, the base class type is set to null. Typically, you should have `class Person`, with subclasses `Tenant` and `Landlord`. The parent class should hold methods/validations that apply to it and its subclasses. While Rails looks at the subclass name and marks it as the type.

Comment: @ioquatix Perhaps either to differentiate between the base class and the subclasses, or because creating an object of a regular class shouldn't require setting a type column (only creating objects of a subclass should require a type column)?

Answer (score 6):

You can *solve* this if you want by adding the `type` column with a default value of `"Person"`.